Proxmox- Failing to ping a container using VLANs
I'm using Proxmox 8.2.4, and fail to reach LXC MQTT broker on VLAN 30, from VLAN 10 (and any other), while other OS installed on VLAN 30 are reached as expected.

VLAN 30, for IoT devices.
VLAN 10, for PCs.
192.168.30.2 - Container, MQTT broker, installed using helper script. All default settings.
pinging from Linux PC and Windows11 PC from 192.168.10.x failed, while succeeded pinging other VM's at 192.168.30.x which are not containers.
Pinging from 192.168.30.x to 192.168.30.2 - ping succeeds.
Pinging from 192.168.30.2 to 192.168.10.x - fails.

Appreciate any help to access MQTT broker from my PCs VLAN.
Guy
